# JavaFX : Supply arguments to Task

Tags: java, javafx, task

I am working on a JavaFX project in which I am making network calls with [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html). Unfortunately, I have not been able to find how I can pass arguments to it. I have searched many links, but none of them provides. One link from java2s claims they are passing, but the code does not reflect that.

As you can see from the code below, I am using a for-loop and passing the ID parameter of RestGroupAccount in the URL. This time it's okay because I anyways need all of the RestCanvas.

**But I am interested in knowing how to give parameters to Task**

Code :

```
private Task<List<RestCanvas>> fetchCanvases = new Task<List<RestCanvas>>() {

    @Override
    protected List<RestCanvas> call() throws Exception {
        List<RestCanvas> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            for(RestGroupAccount groupAccount : groupAccounts) {
                RestTemplate rest = StaticRestTemplate.getRest();
                HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                requestHeaders.add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + StaticRestTemplate.jsessionid);
                HttpEntity<RestCanvas> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);
                rest.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
                rest.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
                ResponseEntity<RestCanvas[]> responseEntity = rest.exchange(getCanvasForGroupAccount+groupAccount.getGroupId(), HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, RestCanvas[].class);
                RestCanvas[] restCanvasArray = responseEntity.getBody();
                Collections.addAll(list, restCanvasArray);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;
    }
};
```

If any more information is required, kindly let me know. Thank you.

Comment: If you need to use the code inside your `Task` more than once, you should consider creating non-anonymous subclass and either instantiate it every time you need it with the construction parameter, or create it once with the mutable param.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg Since `Task` is intended to be used in a user-defined thread, using mutable data is almost always an error, because it leads to race conditions. The first approach is the way to do this, with the parameters passed to the constructor being immutable objects.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg : When I create a constructor inside Task, it expects a return type, meaning it has no idea about a constructor.

Comment: @James_D yeah, sure, hard to disagree, although the previous comment cannot be edited.

Comment: @WeareBorg what do you mean by "expects return type"? Show what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg : I am trying to add a constructor inside the Task fetchCanvases as you had suggested, but it is not working. Can you give me an example of what you said in your first comment. Thank you.

Comment: @WeareBorg I think you must have missed the "consider creating non-anonymous subclass" part of that.

Comment: @WeareBorg try smth like http://pastebin.com/GRvZgaC1

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg : Okay, now I get it.. It's similar to Android's AsyncTask what you are referring to I suppose. Okay. I will do that. Thank you. Kindly post that as an answer. Thank you.. :-)

Comment: OK, I'll post as an answer

Comment: Can someone tell me why this was downvoted? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to use the code inside your Task more than once, you should consider creating non-anonymous subclass and instantiate it every time you need it with the construction parameter.

In your example this might be:

```
private Task<List<RestCanvas>> fetchCanvases = new MyTask(getCanvasForGroupAccount + groupAccount.getGroupId());

// ...

// please don't use this name :)
private static class MyTask extends Task<List<RestCanvas>> {
    private final String id;

    public MyTask(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<RestCanvas> call() throws Exception {
        List<RestCanvas> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            for(RestGroupAccount groupAccount : groupAccounts) {
                RestTemplate rest = StaticRestTemplate.getRest();
                HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                requestHeaders.add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + StaticRestTemplate.jsessionid);
                HttpEntity<RestCanvas> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);
                rest.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
                rest.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
                ResponseEntity<RestCanvas[]> responseEntity = rest.exchange(id, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, RestCanvas[].class);
                RestCanvas[] restCanvasArray = responseEntity.getBody();
                Collections.addAll(list, restCanvasArray);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried passing parameters the way you suggested, the call method was not executed, no network call. Here is the code in pastebin..  http://pastebin.com/dKnQPLWJ

Comment: @WeareBorg you don't actually execute the task.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar need, where I needed to create tasks that would take in a File and perform tasks on it. In my case I needed to do different things with files in multiple places, so I created the following class:

```
public abstract class FileOperationTask<V> extends Task<V> {
    protected File file;

    public FileOperationTask(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

This allows me in my controllers to define the following:

```
FileOperationTask<List<RaffleTicket>> task = new FileOperationTask<List<RaffleTicket>>(file){
    @Override
    protected List<RaffleTicket> call() throws Exception {
        this.file.toString();
        return null;
    }
};
new Thread(task).run();
```

As you can see, I'm able to operate on the File object, and implementing my asynchronous task is now more or less identical to implementing a normal task.